# Date Variable shows default value as 00:00:00 in VB 6.0

Tags: date, vb6

I defined a variable as Date in Visual Basic 6.0 as under:

```
Dim procDate as Date
```

It was working fine and accepted date derived from database.

Today, I got error showing data type mismatch for this variable.
When I checked its default value, it shows 00:00:00 which is time format without date value.

What could be reason for this?

Comment: Show us how you're checking its "default value".

Comment: And what operation are you performing that shows a type mismatch?

Comment: I derive date value from table which is returned by a function and same is formatted in date only:  'code' ProcDate = Format(GetValues("Max(DocDate)", "BillBook", "Where CoCode = " & gsCompCode & "", cnnEureka), "MMM YYYY")

Comment: DocDate is date filed in table named "BillBook",  gsCompCode is global variable for company for which user is working, cnnEureka is connection for MS Access 2007

Comment: Is that the line causing the type mismatch?

Comment: I checked my other VB projects and I find similar for date variables: error no 13 Type mismatch message.

Comment: Maybe you should check the return value of `GetValues()`. It may not be a value that VB can cast to a date. For example, if `GetValues()` returns `"abc"`, how is that supposed to be interpreted as a date? What is the return type of `GetValues()`?

Comment: @Bond I checked in Object browser, it shows:  
Property Date As Variant
    Member of VBA.DateTime
    Sets or returns the current system date
Is this ok?

Comment: Return type of function GetValues(...) is variant.

Comment: And what _value_ is it returning when you get the type mismatch error? You should guard against invalid values: `Dim v As Variant`...`v = GetValues(...)`... `If IsDate(v) Then procDate = Format(v, "MMM YYYY")`.

Comment: @Bond Thanks for help. Able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be assigning a string to ProcDate.

This is the rules for assigning a string that `Format` produces so a Date. It's known as `Let` coercion.

> **String to Date**
>
> If the source string can be interpreted as either a date/time, time, or date value (in that precedence order) according to the **host-defined regional settings**, the value is converted to a Date.
>
> Otherwise, if the source string can be interpreted as a number or currency value according to the host-defined regional settings, and the resulting value is within the magnitude range of Double, the value is converted to the nearest representable Double value, and then this value is Let-coerced to Date. If this coerced value is within the range of Date, the result is the date value.
>
> If the source string could not be interpreted as a date/time, time, date, number or currency value, runtime error 13 (Type mismatch) is raised. If the conversion to Double resulted in an overflow, runtime error 13 (Type mismatch) is raised instead of the runtime error 6 (Overflow) that would otherwise be raised.